# Why is the conditional expectation of prediction error in regression not zero?

Tags: regression, expected-value

The conditional expectation of the error in regression is:

$E[Y-X\beta|X=x]$  is not equal to 0. Why is this the case? If you fix all the predictor variables, why does $E[Y]$ - $X\beta$ not equal to 0?

Comment: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/13/lectures/ch02.pdf. I am referring to the notes here concerning prediction error under 2.13. I am not sure how the result was arrived at.

Comment: The normal convention is to use $\beta$ for a true (population) coefficient and $\hat\beta$ for its value as estimated by regression on sample data.  Do you mean $\hat\beta$?

Comment: Yes. The sample.

Comment: @AdamBailey No, if you read through the link to Ch 2 of the book, $X\beta$ is the true linear approximation to $E(Y \mid X=x)$.  Note that $E(Y \mid X=x)\neq X\beta$ in reality, see my answer below and section 2.1 of the book.  This equation does not actually have to do with prediction error, which we commonly think of as $Y-\hat{Y}$, which you are correct that such an equation for predicted values after running a regression would involve $\hat{\beta}$.  Perhaps this is partly where Phil is confused?

Comment: @jsk So we can distinguish a) the population regression function, b) a linear model fitted to the whole population, c) a linear model fitted to a sample, and Ch 2 concerns the relation between (a) and (b), not (a) and (c)?

Comment: @AdamBailey Ch 2 does more than just compare (a) and (b), but yes, this particular equation from the chapter is pointing out the distinction between (a) and (b).

Answer (score 1):

The argument appears to be that the model $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$ is only a linear approximation of the actual relationship between $Y$ and $X$.  Since this is only an approximation of reality, there will some values for $X$ where $E(Y\mid X=x) < x\beta$ and other values of $X$ for which $E(Y\mid X=x) > x\beta$.  Here's figure 1.3 from chapter 1.

[image: figure 1.3].

In this figure, the blue wavy line is the actual expected $Y$ for each $x$, which is sometimes above and sometimes below the linear approximation of the relationship (red line).